# Counting unique records across 2 columns and computing a score based on boolean values

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like this in Google Big Query:

```
custID  InteractionDate Purchased?  Sales
1       20150312           F         0
1       20150312           T         200
1       20150314           T         150
2       20150221           T         400
2       20150221           F         0
2       20150221           T         120
```

..that I need to transform to the following structure:

```
 custID InteractionDate Success Sales
 1     20150312          0.5    200
 1     20150314           1     150
 2     20150221         0.66    520
```

..where in this second table the success column is defined as

```
count(purchase=Yes)/(count(purchase=Yes) + count(purchase=No)),
```

and sales is just the sum.

I'm quite new to BQ and no-SQL languages. I simply don't know how to do this, I've searched and seen examples that suggest using partition over but I simply haven't seen any example that does just this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This is a very simple, basic, `GROUP BY` query for SQL. Does Big Query support basic SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be very simple in SQL. As far as I can read the [BigQuery Query reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference), it supports all (`GROUP BY` clause, `COUNT()` and `SUM()` functions, `CASE` expressions):

```
SELECT 
    custID, InteractionDate,
    1.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN Purchased = 'T' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) AS Success,
    SUM(Sales) AS Sales
FROM
    tableName
GROUP BY
    custID, InteractionDate ;
```

Comment: Posted the same question on stack overflow and this is the simpler of the answers I've got so far. Cheers bud. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this one:

```
SELECT custID,
       InteractionDate,
       IFNULL(ROUND((yes)/(yes+NO), 2),0) AS Success,
       sales
FROM
  (SELECT custID,
          InteractionDate,
          sum(if(Purchased=='T',1,0)) AS yes,
          sum(if(Purchased!='T',1,0)) AS NO,
          sum(sales) AS sales
   FROM
     (SELECT 1 AS custID,
             20150312 AS InteractionDate,
             'F' AS Purchased,
             0 AS Sales),
     (SELECT 1 AS custID,
             20150312 AS InteractionDate,
             'T' AS Purchased,
             200 AS Sales),
     (SELECT 1 AS custID,
             20150314 AS InteractionDate,
             'T' AS Purchased,
             150 AS Sales),
     (SELECT 2 AS custID,
             20150221 AS InteractionDate,
             'T' AS Purchased,
             400 AS Sales),
     (SELECT 2 AS custID,
             20150221 AS InteractionDate,
             'F' AS Purchased,
             0 AS Sales),
     (SELECT 2 AS custID,
             20150221 AS InteractionDate,
             'T' AS Purchased,
             120 AS Sales)
   GROUP BY custID,
            InteractionDate)
```

in a simpler way:

```
SELECT custID,
       InteractionDate,
       round(sum(if(Purchased=='T',1,0))/(sum(if(Purchased=='T',1,0))+sum(if(Purchased!='T',1,0))),2),
       sum(sales) AS sales
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY custID,
         InteractionDate
```

Comment: Cheers bud! Used the simpler version. Works perfectly!